# Drawing Library for Ruby

Tags: ruby, graphics, drawing

I am trying to code a flowchart generator for a language using Ruby.

I wanted to know if there were any libraries that I could use to draw various shapes for the various flowchart elements and write out text to those shapes.

I would really prefer not having to write code for drawing basic shapes, if I can help it.

Can someone could point me to some reference documentation with examples of using that library?

Comment: I had the same question, Let me know id there is anything comparable to System.Drawing namespace in .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that (at time of writing) what you want almost certainly didn't exist. Sorry!

If you're Windows-based then I'd look for a product in the .NET space, where I expect you'd find something. You're probably going to have to pay real money though. I suppose, if you're brave, you may be able to talk to it using IronRuby.

From a non-MS environment I would be hoping for a Java-based solution. As already mentioned, within the Web world, you're going to be hoping some something JavaScript-based, or probably more likely, something from the Flash (or maybe even Silverlight?) world.

Actually, if you want to stay in Ruby and don't mind some risk, Silverlight might be a way to go - assuming the DLR stuff actually works (no experience here). Ruby - much as I love it - hardly has the most mature GUI structure around it.

Update: Since writing this (approaching 5 years ago) the situation has improved - a little. While I'm still not aware of any specific Ruby graph-drawing libraries, there is improved support for [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) [here (Github](https://github.com/glejeune/Ruby-Graphviz/)) or by `gem install ruby-graphviz`. I've found that for simple graphs, it's quite possible to write the script directly from Ruby.

Comment: Some libraries do exist for ruby. Although you would have to work only with basic elements. As Nathan pointed out, there's https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick, but there's also https://rubygems.org/gems/cairo. Here's a simple tutorial http://www.hokstad.com/simple-drawing-in-ruby-with-cairo.html. And here's another that uses GTK http://zetcode.com/tutorials/rubygtktutorial/cairo/. I would have to agree that it's not the best API, but it's a start.

Comment: "I need something with Ruby", "Try .NET", WTF.

Comment: @Gaston too bad you didn't make an answer out of that.

Answer (score 17):

Write up your flowchart as a directed or undirected graph in [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/About.php).  Graphviz has a language, [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) that makes it easy to generate graphs.  Just generate the dot file, run it through Graphiviz, and you get your image.

```
graph {
  A -- B -- C;
  B -- D;
  C -- D [constraint=false];
}
```

renders as 
[image: undirected]

```
digraph {
  A [label="start"];
  B [label="eat"];
  C [label="drink"];
  D [label="be merry"];

  A -> B -> C;
  C -> D [constraint=false];
  B -> D [ arrowhead=none, arrowtail=normal]; // reverse this edge
}
```

renders as
[image: directed]

You can control node shapes and much more in Graphviz.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're going to be limited mainly by the capabilities of whatever user agent you're building for; if this is a web project, drawing capabilities are going to be dependent on the browser. Since Ruby is running server-side, you would at minimum need some JavaScript to allow dragging/zooming, etc. There's plenty of examples of JavaScript being used for vector drawing (just google "javascript graphics library"), but all require coding, and I haven't seen any library that abstracts this elegantly.

ImageMagick has a Ruby binding called RMagick (sometimes known by other names, depending on the repository). ([Link](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/))
I haven't used it myself, but I believe it will do what you're looking for. You will need to do some coding, but it's along the lines of

```
draw.rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
draw.polygon(x1, y1,...,xN, yN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am totally sure, but check out cairo bindings for ruby. Pango for text. I am investigating then currently and came across this page.